# Azimuthally Symmetric Potential for a Spherical Conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, conductors

I am trying to solve problem 2-13 from my textbook "Principles of Electrodynamics" (see image below).

I believe that I should be solving the potential as

$
\varphi(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (A_n r^n + \frac{B_n}{r^{n+1}})P_n(\cos\theta),
$

where $A_n$ and $B_n$ are determined by the boundary condition of the conductor. For $r < R$ we should have that $B_n = 0$ to make sure the potential is finite and for $r > R$ we should have that $A_n = 0$ to ensure that the potential goes to 0 at infinity. That being said, at r=R, we can apply the boundary conditions such that we

$A_n^{in} = \frac{2n+1}{2a^n}\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(R,\theta)P_n(\cos\theta)d\cos\theta$

and

$B_n^{out} = \frac{2n+1}{2}a^{n+1}\int_{-1}^{1}\varphi(R,\theta)P_n(\cos\theta)d\cos\theta$.

Now, my problem comes when I want to solve these two integrals because it appears to me that if I apply the boundary condition, namely that

$
\varphi = 0 \;\;\;\; \frac{3}{2}  < \cos\theta < 1\\
\varphi = \varphi_0 \;\;\;\; \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}  < \cos\theta < \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\varphi = 0 \;\;\;\; -1  < \cos\theta < -\frac{3}{2}
$

then the above two integrals reduce to

$A_n^{in} = \frac{2n+1}{2a^n}\int_{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\varphi_0P_n(\cos\theta)d\cos\theta$

and

$B_n^{out} = \frac{2n+1}{2}a^{n+1}\int_{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\varphi_0P_n(\cos\theta)d\cos\theta$

respectively.

Now, since $P_n$ are odd functions for odd $n$, $A_n^{in}$ and $B_n^{out}$ appear to be 0 for all of the odd values of n. However, the problem arises now when I am trying to evaluate these integrals in general for even values of $n$, in this case the results seem intractable because I am trying to integrate the Legendre Polynomials over a symmetric interval where the limits are not -1 and 1.

From my understanding, this problem should be as straightforward as applying the boundary conditions as I have done to solve for the potential, is there something that I am overlooking?

[image]

Comment: Hint: You need to evaluate only a few of the coefficients to answer all the subproblems.

Comment: That seems easy enough for part (a), but for part (b) don't I need to evaluate $\frac{\partial \varphi(r,\theta)}{\partial r}|_{r=R}$ to obtain the charge distribution? In which case I need a full expression for $\varphi(r,\theta)$?

Comment: In part (b), you are asked to calculate the total charge but not how it is distributed over the sphere. For the latter question, one should know all the coefficients, but this is certainly too much information for the former.

Hint for part (b): Gauss's law.

Comment: From Gauss's law we have that $\int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$ but it's not apparent to me how this is helpful since I don't know what $\vec{E}$ looks like...?

Comment: How does Gauss's law relate the total charge to $A_{n}^{\mathrm{in}}$ and $B_{n}^{\mathrm{out}}$? (Take a spherical Gaussian surface of radius $a>R$. Taking $a$ to infinity may help but is not necessary.)

Comment: I'm still having trouble... could I bother you for another hint?

Comment: In fact, the expression for the potential for $r>R$, i.e., $\sum_{n} B_{n}^{\mathrm{out}} r^{-n-1}P_{n}(\cos\theta)$ is exactly of the form of a multipole expansion.

Comment: Hi, I still don't see what your getting at actually, because it seems like the monopole term doesn't necessarily vanish here, which means that not all the terms are 2^n poles, which means that the total charge shouldnt necessarily be 0. Oh! Is the total charge  $R\varphi_0$ !?

Comment: Comparison with the multipole expansion formula tells you that $B_{0}^{\mathrm{out}} = Q/4\pi\epsilon_{0}$.